# Multiple questions about magnetic levitation including modelling and how to achieve it

Tags: electromagnetism, control, control-system, pid-controller, electromagnetic

I have several questions regarding magnetic levitation.  If I have missed something in one of these questions then please do let me know.

I am working on a magnetic levitation project using an Arduino and have so far researched into its background such as PID closed loop control systems, force given from a solenoid and ferromagnets vs diamagnets.

The thing is, however, that most calculations I see about the systems get me confused, because it seems whenever I research into how people achieve levitation, they use some already established system in which they make equations of, such as [for example, this post.](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/553433/modeling-magnetic-levitation-system-with-current-as-the-input-signal)

How would I get to those equations? Are those connected to a PID formula?

Secondly, as I am working on a type of levitation where an object gets levitated above four small solenoids, each with a strength of 0.37N (Total 1.49N) with current 2.35A and at 2.5cm distance, what type of disc magnet should be used to be suspended above the solenoids? Futhermore, these type of systems normally have a ferrite ring magnet outside the solenoids. Does its pole have to be opposite that of the solenoid? (as in if the solenoid's top is North, should the ferrite facing up be South?)

Thirdly, are there proper wiring diagrams/research papers or even tutorials that use the four solenoid/levitate above solenoid idea, or is this just not feasible at all? I only find inaccurate articles about the subject or some low quality 12 second video with a guy who's already found the answer but won't share how he did it.

These are the parts that I have

- 4.18mH for each four small solenoids of 15mm height and 22mm diameter
- 49mH solenoid with a soft iron core, height is 59.5mm and diameter is 56.5mm
- TC4420 MOSFET driver and an IRF620 transistor for the big coil
- LN298 H-bridge for smaller coils
- Ferrite ring magnet of 100mm, internal diameter 60mm (I do not know its force because I ripped it from some old tech)
- Supposed [neodymium](https://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/B091YNBQFH/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_asin_title_o05_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1) magnets with "10kg force" (could not find any better apart from alibaba which comes all the way next year)
- Arduino Nano

**EDIT**: After re-reading I realised I made a mistake in not providing a design of my system. This is what it is supposed to look like:

[image]

Four solenoids encased with a ferrite ring magnet as mentioned previously along with a magnetic disc levitating above it.

Comment: What kind of maglev (for context) ? Passive diamagnetic, passive superconducting or active ferromagnetic ? Probably the last?! Make sure not to get confused by articles about the former 2 then. Is it acceptable to use a single coil from top (and use gravity as antagonist) ? Please add these details to your question

Comment: I can affirm that it uses both an electromagnet with iron cores along with a ferrite ring magnet outside it. (check above image for reference). That also is acceptable, but when I tried to work with it using the parts I had (being the MOSFER IRF620 and a TC4420 Gate driver) it did not switch at all, and the idea was scrapped. However, if you do have any idea of how to operate a MOSFET properly using a gate driver, do let me know. Thank you